# table joins sub category with php loops

Tags: php, loops, join, categories

i have two tables Category and sub category in php i want to show them in accordion
but my code is not working please help. below are the columns on two tables.
category = c_id, category_name.
sub_category = sub_cat_id, sub_cat_name, c_id

```
  <?php
  $sql="select * from category";
  $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
  ?>
  <li class="subMenu"><a> <?php echo $row["category_name"]?> [840] </a>
  <ul style="display:none">             
  <?php
  $sql1="SELECT * FROM category INNER JOIN sub_category ON 
  sub_category.cat_id = category.cat_id;";
  $res1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);


  while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($res1))
  {
  ?>

  <li><a href="products.html"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i><?php echo 
  $row1["sub_cat_name"]?></a></li>

  <?php } // while loop
   ?>           
  </ul>
  </li>

  <?php
  }
```

Comment: What "not working" means to you?

Comment: i want to display this in a accordion first category name when you click it it will opens the subcategories

Comment: I understand what you want to do. The point is, what is "not working" ?

Comment: the second loop is not working the main categories are showing but the subcategories are not i think i might be using the wrong query ?

Comment: Its a bootstrap accordion

Answer (score 0):

Hi just used this query in my second while loop and now its working fine

Query  $sql1="select * from sub_category WHERE cat_id = ".$row['cat_id']."";